AWS Greengrass component MQTT message is not showing in MQTT client test in console
i wrote following python code to send a message over MQTT to all subscribers, its also sending fine no exception there i checked the greengrass logs. The problem is the published message is not showing on AWS console in MQTT client Test section.
import json
import psutil
import subprocess
from time import sleep
from requests import request
from awsiot.greengrasscoreipc.clientv2 import GreengrassCoreIPCClientV2

client = GreengrassCoreIPCClientV2()
TOPIC = "eeai/edge/health"

def GetHealth():
    CPU = psutil.cpu_percent(4)
    RAM = psutil.virtual_memory()[2]
    storage = psutil.disk_usage('/')

    network = False
    try:
        stdoutdata = subprocess.check_output("ethtool eth0 | grep Link", shell=True)
        network = "yes" in str(stdoutdata).lower()
    except:
        network = False

    sensors = psutil.sensors_temperatures()
    summary = []
    for name, entries in sensors.items():
        response = []
        for entry in entries:
            status = 'High' if entry[2] is not None else 'Critical' if entry[3] is not None else 'Normal'
            response.append({ "tag": entry[0], "temp": entry[1], "status": status })
            summary.append({ "name": name, "detail": response })


    return json.dumps({
        'processor': str(CPU),
        'ram': str(RAM),
        'storage': str(storage[3]),
        'network': network,
        'other': summary,
        'detail': {}
    })

def publish_health():
    while True:
        data = GetHealth()
        try:
            client.publish_to_iot_core(topic_name=TOPIC, qos='1', payload=data)
            print("MQTT_SUBMISSION_SUCCESSFULL")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print("Skipping mqtt health submission")
        sleep(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    publish_health()


